B2B commerce cart status sometimes stuck on active status
We encountered a problem where the cart status occasionally remains active when the user is redirected to the checkout page, resulting in an error message stating, "You don't have access to checkout." My question is, which component is responsible for changing the cart status from active to checkout?
